# Why is mouse click event listener breakpoint hit in a blackboxed script in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find out which Javascript method is called when I click a button. I have blackboxed some third party javascript files. I am using the latest versions of Chrome and Canary.

I have enabled the Mouse click event listener breakpoint in devtools. When I click a button, a debugger breakpoint is hit inside a js file which is blackboxed. I am using a third party button whose JS click event handler executes first before mine. I have blackboxed their code file hoping that my code gets the breakpoint.  A 'This script is blackboxed in debugger' yellow message shows up for their code file.

Why is the breakpoint hit when the script file is blackboxed?

Answer (score 0):

I created a test where I added a `click` Event Listener Breakpoint on this page and it paused in `jquery-min.js`. I blackboxed that script and tried again. It didn't break in jQuery anymore.

I re-read your post and you mentioned 'a debugger breakpoint is hit'. I now take that to mean an explicit breakpoint like a `debugger;` statement in the source code or one set in Dev Tools (by clicking line number), and that the Event Listener Breakpoint is irrelevant.

If you have a `debugger;` statement in a library that is blackboxed, the breakpoint will still be hit. You can disable the breakpoint by right clicking on the line number where the statement exists and selecting 'Never pause here'.

[image: Never pause here]

As it stands, if you put a breakpoint in a blackboxed library via Dev Tools, it will still break in that script. It shows more explicit intent to break on the code, rather than something perhaps left in by a 3rd party. You would have to disable or remove them.

There appears to be a debate about whether blackboxing a script should ignore breakpoints set in that library, as blackboxing could be considered to be more about not stepping into the library code/seeing it in the call stack. See the discussion [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506510). Interestingly, the documentation includes the following still:

> The debugger will not pause on any breakpoints set in library code.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing

This isn't the case.

There is come inconsistency here with the behaviour and documentation. I will try and get an update on this.

Comment: I don't have a debugger statement anywhere and do not have an explicit breakpoint anywhere. Otherwise that is expected behavior.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich If you have no breakpoints other than the `click` Event Listener Breakpoint added in Dev Tools, then it shouldn't be pausing in the blackboxed script. Can you provide some sample to test with?

Comment: I know. That's why I posted the question. Sample won't do any good. The whole app needs to be looked at. Thanks. Anyway I found another way to get to what I want.